# JCLI - Jira Command Line need to specific Columns

Tags: jira

I am running ca query in JCLI which is giving huge output

```
jira --action getIssueList  --user ColdBear --password Eskimo jira --server http://Cold.bear.com:8080 --file "E:\temp\Test.csv" --search "Project=Colder AND createdDate >= 2013-04-02 AND createdDate <= 2013-04-10" --outputFormat 999 -v >>err2c.log
```

Error file is also huge

I have tried formats 200 and 998 but not all fields are coming(some are custom)
Issue Type
Key 
Summary 
Description 
Assignee
Reporter
Priority
Status
Resolution
Created 
Resolved
User Impacted
Updated 
Root Cause
Linked Issues

Can i Choose specific Fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose specific fields like this:
 --columns "key,2,custom1,custom2"

Source: https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/Examples

Comment: Thanks, got that working, but for some reason the Resolved and Issue type are not getting listed I am using the output format 999 which is for all the columns

Comment: It seems to be caused by your configuration. I am getting everything using format 999.